# Making changes to app after deploy to heroku and running npm build

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I deployed my REACT application to Heroku and everything works fine but how do I run it locally and make changes? when I use npm start it boots up on port 8080 (which was the port I was told to use by a tutorial) but not on 3000. When I got to localhost:8080 my website is there but any changes I make are not displayed even after refreshing.

I just want to make changes locally and then redeploy the changes to Heroku.

```
    Here is my server.js 

    const express = require('express');
const favicon = require('express-favicon');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/build/favicon.ico'));
// the __dirname is the current directory from where the script is running
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
    return res.send('pong');
});
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(port);

Here is my package.json

    {
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.9",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "aphrodite": "^2.4.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-favicon": "^2.0.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-animate-on-scroll": "^2.1.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any changes you made locally cannot reflect in the server by itself.

You must deploy the changes to the server using git or deploy only the build folder, each time you make a new version.

Comment: But how do I run the project locally again so I can see the changes and then redeploy to Heroku?

Comment: I don't understand. How you deployed in the first place??
you must check it out first, right?